# Recursively fill array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, recursion, multidimensional-array

I am trying to fill an array ***I*** Using a recursive formula. The formula is shown below. 
[image]

In this formula I already computed the ***B*** array and I know all the elements and ***M*** is the dimension of ***B*** array which is equal to dimension of ***I*** array. ***u,v*** and ***w*** letters indicate indices. My function is:

```
function I_matrix = fill_I_recursively(B_matrix, u_ind, v_ind, w_ind)
M = size(B_matrix,1);
if u_ind == 1 && v_ind == 1 && w_ind == 1
    I_matrix(u_ind,v_ind,w_ind) = 0; 
else
    if w_ind > 1
        I_matrix(u_ind,v_ind,w_ind) = fill_I_recursively(B_matrix, u_ind, v_ind, w_ind-1) + B_matrix(u_ind,v_ind,w_ind-1);
    elseif v_ind > 1
        I_matrix(u_ind,v_ind,w_ind) = fill_I_recursively(B_matrix, u_ind, v_ind-1, M-1) + B_matrix(u_ind,v_ind-1,M-1);
    else
        I_matrix(u_ind,v_ind,w_ind) = fill_I_recursively(B_matrix, u_ind-1,  M-1, M-1) + B_matrix(u_ind-1,M-1,M-1);
   end
end
```

I call this function in my program:

```
I_matrix = NaN(max_boxes,max_boxes,max_boxes);
%%fill the I matrix using recursive function
for u_ind = 1:max_boxes
    for v_ind = 1:max_boxes
        for w_ind = 1:max_boxes
            I_matrix(u_ind,v_ind,w_ind) = fill_I_recursively(B_matrix, u_ind, v_ind, w_ind);
        end
    end
end
```

When it runs I get the error message "Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts". Could you please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: It's unclear to me why this needs to be recursive. Why can't you just start at `0,0,0` (or `1,1,1` for MATLAB indexing) and fill the matrix by looping up through `u`, `v` and `w`? The elements of `I` only ever depend on previously computed values - i.e. a lower or equal index for `u`, `v` or `w. Recursion over complicates this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises due to the difference in expectations for your `fill_I_recursively` function.

In your function definition, the output is `I_matrix`, which is a multidimensional array.

In your main program, the expected output of `fill_I_recursively` is a scalar, that is filled into an entry of the `I_matrix` multidimensional array.

You should alter one of the two sections so that they are consistent.

Here's an example of how to modify your function definition to output a scalar:

```
function I_uvw = fill_I_recursively(B_matrix, u_ind, v_ind, w_ind)
M = size(B_matrix,1);
if u_ind == 1 && v_ind == 1 && w_ind == 1
    I_uvw = 0; 
else
    if w_ind > 1
        I_uvw = fill_I_recursively(B_matrix, u_ind, v_ind, w_ind-1) + B_matrix(u_ind,v_ind,w_ind-1);
    elseif v_ind > 1
        I_uvw = fill_I_recursively(B_matrix, u_ind, v_ind-1, M-1) + B_matrix(u_ind,v_ind-1,M-1);
    else
        I_uvw = fill_I_recursively(B_matrix, u_ind-1,  M-1, M-1) + B_matrix(u_ind-1,M-1,M-1);
   end
end
```